# Probability of die game

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> You and your best friend decide to play a game of chance with dice.
>   There are two dice. One green and one yellow. The green dice is not
>   well balanced so it gives you a chance of 1/3 of getting a 6 and an
>   equal chance on the remaining numbers. The yellow dice is normal. Your
>   friend gives you the choice of playing with the green or yellow dice.
>   The game now goes like this. You roll your dice and your friend rolls
>   hers. Whomever has the highest number wins. If the numbers are the
>   same, the player with the yellow dice wins. Which dice should you
>   choose?

I'm not sure how to do this problem... $P($Yellow - 6$|$Yellow wins$) = \frac{P(6)P($Yellow wins$|6)}{P($Yellow win$)}$

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the probability this way:

1. both get 6
2. yellow 6 green other
3. green 6 yellow other
4. both less than 6 and tie
5. both less than 6 and no tie.

Compute the chance of each one.  The green die wins 3 and half of 5

Comment: 1. (1/3)(1/6) = 1/18, 2. (2/3)(1/6) = 2/18, 3. (1/3)(5/6) = 5/18... not sure about the other 2?

Comment: For 4, what is the chance that yellow is, say, $5$?  That green is $ 5$?  Multiply these, then multiply by $5$ because the number you tie at doesn't matter.  For $5$, just subtract the sum of all the others from $1$.

Comment: So, (1/6)(1/6)(5) = (5/36)?

Comment: No, the chance that green is $5$ is not $1/6$, but you are close